# Параллельное выполнение в случае вложенных циклов

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть вложенный циклы, в результате они вызывают функцию для расчета данных, входными параметрами которой являются 2 параметра `index` в циклах. Как можно максимально эффективно реализовать распараллеливание прохода по циклам? По сути, я имею полный перебор двух параметров.

```
double optResult = 0;
double result = 0;
for (int i = 5; i < 50; i = i + 5)
{
    for (int j = 5; j < 50; j = j + 5)
    {
        if (i < j)
        {
            optResult = OptimStart(i,j);
            if (optResult > result)
            {
                result = optResult;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал как то так

```
void Main()
{
    var tuples = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

    for (int i = 5; i < 50; i = i + 5)
    {
        for (int j = i+5; j < 50; j = j + 5)
        {           
                tuples.Add(Tuple.Create(i, j));
        }
    }

    var max = tuples.AsParallel().Max(t=>Foo(t.Item1, t.Item2));
    Console.WriteLine(max);
}


int Foo(int i, int j)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);     
    return i+j;     
}
```

Если комбинаций слишком много и не хочется держать их в памяти, то

```
void Main()
{       
    var max = GetItems().AsParallel().Max(t=>Foo(t.Item1, t.Item2));
    Console.WriteLine(max);
}


int Foo(int i, int j)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);             
    return i+j;     
}

IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetItems()
{
    for (int i = 5; i < 50; i = i + 5)
    {
        for (int j = i + 5; j < 50; j = j + 5)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Буду разбираться во всем. Только заранее, все расчеты в функции `OptimStart` в данном примере прописывать где именно? Там много расчетов будет и половина нужно будет потом в кэше оставлять.

Comment: В моем примере функцию ```OptimStart ``` я заменил на ```Foo``` - то есть вам вместо вызова моего ```Foo``` надо вызывать вашу функцию

Comment: А, пока я не вдавался в подробности, думал, что return i+j влияет на многопоточность. Теперь всё понятно, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Можно вложенный цикл начинать не с `5`, а с `i + 5`, тогда внутреннее условие `if (i < j)` можно убрать:

```java
double optResult = 0;
double result = 0;
for (int i = 5; i < 50; i = i + 5) {
    for (int j = i + 5; j < 50; j = j + 5) {
        optResult = OptimStart(i, j);
        if (optResult > result) {
            result = optResult;
        }
    }
}
```